# Expressing variable in terms of other independent variables.

Tags: proof-writing

I am going through a proof for the existence of temperature (a proof written in C. J. Adkins equilibrium thermodynamics, if anyone is interested) and I am confused about one of the steps. I am hoping someone will be able to clarify it for me.

Before anyone starts up: I would ask in physics but I think the bit I am stuck on is the maths trick being used and I do not want to confuse things even more.

Starting with the condition for equilibrium for 1 and 3.

$$F_1=(p_1,V_1,p_3,V_3)=0$$

Next the condition for equilibrium for 2 and 3.

$$F_2=(p_2,V_2,p_3,V_3)=0$$

Solving both for $p_3$

$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)=0$$

$$p_3=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)=0$$

and equating the two:

$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

Next is the bit I do not get because he solves for $p_1$

$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

What happened between $p_3$ and $p_1$? I have no idea what trick he did to get away with doing that. The bit afterwards is made vague if I just accept it without knowing why so I would be keen to get some ideas here because he then solves for $p_1$ like this

*(the physics bit) 
and by the zeroth law this must be true:*

$$F_3=(p_1,V_1,p_2,V_2)=0$$

Ok back to the maths:

$$p_1=f_3(V_1,p_2,V_2)$$

Which apparently means $V_3$ can drop out of

$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

But it comes across like he did it and said "I did it so that proves I can do it". I do not know how he did it and it looks a bit like he is cheating without seeing that step!

$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1)=f_2(p_2,V_2)$$

Anyway I get the rest (provided the previous stuff was true) but I may as well finish it for the sake of completeness:

$$\Phi_1(p_1,V_1)=\Phi_2(p_2,V_2)$$

Which proves the existence of temperature.

Adkins has clearly never had a thermostat war or he'd not have needed all that but anyway... I would really appreciate some explanations of the bit I am confused on.

EDIT:

Please observe the bit where I say the next is the bit I do not get because he solves for $p_1$

$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

EDIT:

The [amazon look inside](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521274567) shows the proof which is in the first few pages under the zeroth law chapter

Comment: The notation is unclear.  It looks like the first equality sign immediately after $F_1$ and $F_2$ should be removed so that equilibrium conditions are $F_i(a,b,c,d)=0$. Maybe $F_1 = F_2$ if the same physical law is applied to the different quadruples.  Is there an online link to the page of the book where this is done?

Comment: @zyx thanks. I added a link to the question.

Comment: Thanks.  Adkins does write the equations as $F_i(...) = 0$.  He allows for the possibility of different $F_i$ for different *types of* systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the equilibrium of 1 and 3; and 2 and 3 the first relation of $p_1$ is derived such as
$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2,V_3)$$
As next point transitivity is employed between systems. Because of transivity condition systems 1 and 2 are also in equilibrium and there exists a transitive closure (smallest transitive relation) which is given by below relation
$$F_3(p_1,V_1,p_2,V_2)=0$$
which can be solved for $p_1$
$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2)$$
In summary transivity closure is used to eliminate system 3 from the solution set which also eliminates $V_3$ from the relation.

-------Extension for derivation of $p_1$---------

The equilibrium condition between systems 1 and 3 is given by
$$F_1(p_1,V_1,p_3,V_3)=0$$
which can be solved explicitly to find $p_3$
$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)$$
The equilibrium condition between systems 2 and 3 is given by
$$F_2(p_2,V_2,p_3,V_3)=0$$
which can be solved explicitly to find $p_3$
$$p_3=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

Since bot definiton of $p_3$ is same and we can eliminate $p_3$ such as
$$p_3=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)\Rightarrow G(p_1,p_2,V_1,V_2,V_3)=f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)-f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)=0$$
This equation can be solved explicitly for $p_1$
$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2,V_3)$$

Comment: By the equilibrium of 1 and 3; and 2 and 3 the first relation of $p_1$ is derived such as
$$p_1=g(V_1,p_2,V_2,V_3)$$? When was it derived? I didn't see it get derived. That is why I am asking about it.

Comment: I guess it shall be clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I truly do not get the point what's wrong? I guess at first he expressed pressure, that is needed to reach equilibrium for the states 1 and 3 then he did the same for the state 2 and 3 and then said that with this pressure ($p_3$) states 1 and 3, and 2 and 3 will be in equilibrium simultaneously, so we can try to connect the parameter in those states. So he equated them:

$f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3)=f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)$

And equating them he excluded variable $p_3$.
I guess this is all about it.

Comment: I think the part that is in question is after the steps you are considering.

Answer (score 0):

The part in question looks to be the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) (IFT) to me.

If we define $f = f_1(p_1,V_1,V_3) - f_2(p_2,V_2,V_3)$, then $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^{1+4} \to \mathbb{R}$.

If you can show that $f$ satisfies the conditions of IFT (which I guess is the case...

I don't have the book, so I don't know what conditions of $f_1,f_2$ are), you can just apply the theorem.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: You should not need the book the zeroth law isn't the bit I am confused about. I do think it is the IFT but I understood the first application of it (for $p_3$) it was just what he did with $p_1$ that I could not see where it came from.

Comment: Then I must be confused.  You asked  "What happened between $p_3$ and $p_1$? I have no idea what trick he did to get away with doing that."  My answer does not answer your question?

Comment: Nope, sorry it doesn't. because I explained the bit I was stuck on and that's not the bit you clarified.